# How to edit a Word file using Excel VBA or any suggested programme?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm wondering how could I edit a particular word or phrase in the word document by writing some Excel VBA codes? Or, any other recommended program to do so?

For example, my Word document is like the following,

> Dear FRIEND,
>                        ## Greeting on DATE ##
>
> How are you? xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Cheers,     Kevin

My goal is to search for `FRIEND` and then replace a name that I may want to use like `Peter`, and then search for `DATE` and replace a date say `28th Sept, 2017`.

Hope someone could help me with this! Many thanks!
Cheers,
Kevin

Comment: You might want to use Word's mail merge feature; no VBA needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some bookmarks:

Instead of replacing some text by something else you could place a bookmark named Friend or Date in the choosen place and then write on the bookmarks like this

`ThisDocument.Bookmarks("NAME_OF_THE_BOOKMARK").Range.Text ="your text"`

To place a bookmark you have to click on the selected area and then go on **Insert->Bookmarks**